# subprocess.Popen is not able to execute tshark command in Linux in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, tshark

I am trying to execute a tshark command to get some output for a validation and using subprocess.Popen to get this work done, but i am seeing sometimes subprocess.Popen is not able to execute the command. Below is a small function of my code:

```
import subprocess
import logging

def fetch_avps(request_name, logger, tcpdump, port, session_id):
    out_list = []
    if request_name == 'CCR':
        com_sessn_filter = """tshark -r "%s" -odiameter.tcp.ports:"%s" -R 'diameter.cmd.code == 272 and diameter.flags.request==1 and !tcp.analysis.retransmission and diameter.flags.T == 0' -Tpdml -Tfields -ediameter.Session-Id -ediameter.CC-Request-Type -ediameter.User-Name -ediameter.Subscription-Id-Data -ediameter.Value-Digits | grep "%s" | cut -f 1-6 --output-delimiter=':'""" %(tcpdump, port, session_id)
    elif request_name == 'CCA':
        com_sessn_filter = """tshark -r "%s" -odiameter.tcp.ports:"%s" -R 'diameter.cmd.code == 272 and diameter.flags.request==0 and !tcp.analysis.retransmission and diameter.flags.T == 0' -Tpdml -Tfields -ediameter.Session-Id -ediameter.CC-Request-Type -ediameter.Result-Code -ediameter.Validity-Time  -ediameter.Value-Digits -ediameter.Unit-Quota-Threshold | grep "%s" | cut -f 1-6 --output-delimiter=':'""" %(tcpdump, port, session_id)
    p = subprocess.Popen(com_sessn_filter, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    command_out_list = (out.strip().split("\n"))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for i in range(len(command_out_list)):
        out_list.append(command_out_list[i].split(":"))
    if out_list[0][0] == '':
        logger.error("Failed to execute Tshark command")
        logger.debug("Failed to execute Tshark command \"%s\" for Session-Id \"%s\"" %(com_sessn_filter, session_id))
    return 0
```

For example in the above code if I have 20 Sessions in a loop then subprocess.Popen might fail to execute around 12-13 times. Any help will be very useful.

Below is the stderr i am getting whenever it fails to execute.

```
(process:11306): GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./glib/gmem.c:165: failed to allocate 4048572208 bytes Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fail to execute"? What output are you getting? In what way is it failing? What is in `stdout` and `stderr` when it fails?

Comment: @Gil Hamilton I have added the stderr in the above question description.

Comment: are you running out of memory maybe?

Comment: I am not sure if it is `subprocess.Popen()` which is unable to perform the task, or rather the called program (resp. one of them) which fails.

Comment: After some research i find that it is tshark which is throwing this error.

Comment: Although you are calling `p.stdout.read()`, you might think about calling `p.wait()` afterwards to ensure the subprocess terminates before the next one is called. Baybe the memory isn't sufficient for even one call of `tshark`, which looks a little bit greedy: `failed to allocate 4048572208 bytes` sounds a lot to me...

Comment: @glglgl i tried adding p.wait() but still facing the same issue. Is there any way in subprocess.Popen to allocate bytes for execution ?

Comment: @pankmish I see two ways to solve this: 1. make `tshark` use less memory or 2. make sure that an allocation of 4048572208 bytes won't fail. You only have a chance to do so if you are on a 64 bit system with enough memory.